# Get a JSON response using a jQuery API

Tags: jquery, json, api

So i'm trying to use an api to get a JSON response, the only problem is that I have no clue how. On the [API Doc](https://soruly.github.io/whatanime.ga/#/) this given as an example:

```
POST /api/search?token={your_api_token} HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host: whatanime.ga

image={Base64 Encoded Image}
```

Then there's this jQuery example:

```
$.post('/search',
   {
      'image': searchImage.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.8)
   },
   function (data, textStatus) {

   }
);
```

I have no clue what to do or how to use it, I tried researching it but I couldnt find a working example that I could modify or use to learn from. Could you point me in the right direction or give me some tips?

Thanks, Gijs de Jong.

Comment: Start in the repo https://github.com/soruly/whatanime.ga. you need a fulll url for the api...not a relative one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically trying to use the API to search for an image.
According to this code snippet, they want the image as base64 data. You should use the FileReader API.  Use the `readAsDataURL()` method to get the base64 encoded string of the file data.  Here is a detailed article on how to do the same.

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/reading-files-using-the-html5-filereader-api

Next thing you want to do is use ht whatanime api to detect the anime.
In the code snippet in the whatanime link you shared, you need to pass the token that you get from the author as part of the query string.  Something like this:

```
data = {'image':<BASE64_String_of_the_image>}
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "whatanime.ga/search?token=<api_token_here>",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: data,
    success: function(r) {
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand it now, now I gotta find a way to use this in c#. Shouldnt be too hard.

Comment: Nope it shouldn't be.